# Remove duplicate from snippet shop loop woocommerce

Tags: php, hook-woocommerce, code-snippets

I have variable products which have two attributes: size and color. When some product has attributes M->red, XL->blue, M->yellow. Below snippet show atrributess M L M and it's ok but I can't find solution how remove duplicate items

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'variations_loop');
function variations_loop() {
    global $product;
    if($product->get_type() == 'variable') {
        foreach($product->get_available_variations() as $key) {
            $variation = wc_get_product($key['variation_id']);
            echo $variation -> attributes['pa_size'];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you give us an idea of the class definition or a link to the documentation? Ultimately you will need to filter the data, but it's a bit difficult to provide you with an example without the definition.

Comment: I don't understand what documentation you need? $variation -> attributes show arrays. At the beginning I thoughts connect all arrayes to one and use array_unique. 

`array(2) {
  ["pa_size"]=>
  string(1) "m"
  ["pa_color"]=>
  string(4) "blue"
}
array(2) {
  ["pa_size"]=>
  string(2) "xl"
  ["pa_color"]=>
  string(6) "yellow"
}
array(2) {
  ["pa_size"]=>
  string(1) "m"
  ["pa_color"]=>
  string(4) "blue"
}`

Comment: And just to clarify, you want to get the unique values by the `pa_size` correct?

Comment: Yes exactly I need unique `pa_size`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments, it sounds like you have the following array:

```php
[
    [
        "pa_size" => "m",
        "pa_color" => "blue"
    ],
    [
        "pa_size" => "xl",
        "pa_color" => "yellow"
    ],
    [
        "pa_size" => "m",
        "pa_color" => "blue"
    ]
]
```

What you will need to do is call array_map ([documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)) to get just the sizes and array_unique ([documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)) to get the unique values.

Once you get those unique values, you can optionally get the products by the size by using array_filter ([documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)).

Here is an example:

```php
// define the products
$products = [
    [
        "pa_size" => "m",
        "pa_color" => "blue"
    ],
    [
        "pa_size" => "xl",
        "pa_color" => "yellow"
    ],
    [
        "pa_size" => "m",
        "pa_color" => "blue"
    ]
];
// get just the "pa_size" values
$productSizes = array_map(function($key, $value) {
    return $value["pa_size"];
}, array_keys($products), array_values($products));
// get the unique "pa_size" values
$uniqueProductSizes = array_unique($productSizes);

// loop over the unique "pa_size" values
foreach ($uniqueProductSizes as $key => $value) {
    // get every product by the "pa_size"
    $productsBySize = array_filter($products, function($innerKey) use ($value) {
        return $value === $innerKey["pa_size"];
    });
}
```

Fiddle: https://onlinephp.io/c/d637f

Comment: Your solution is great :)